# Can comments on deleted answers still be seen by the @user?

Tags: support, comments

Somehow, not noticing I was reading the meta site or even reading the question properly, I mistakenly posted an answer to the wrong question:

> The OP is asking a question about (is a question appropriate to ask on the main site). You've posted an answer to that secondary question (the theoretical main site post), but not the top most question being asked about (the "is it appropriate" meta post). – 1201ProgramAlarm 2 hours ago
>
> @1201ProgramAlarm. D'oh! Yes, I occasionally forget which half of the site I'm looking at. Thanks. – Ray Butterworth 1 min ago

What I'm wondering is, now that I've deleted the answer, will @1201ProgramAlarm know that I replied to the comment?

(Note that I'm asking about the general case, not about this specific example of question, answer, comment, or @user.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notifications for comments posted in a deleted answer/question are shown between the inbox messages only when the comment was posted from a moderator.
If the user receives emails for answers to his questions, comments, and chat notifications, he can notice a comment has been posted, if the email is sent before the answer/question has been deleted.

Otherwise, the user could see the comment if he is able to see deleted posts and visits the question page.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the user has enough reputation to see a deleted post, I don't think they will be able to see the response. However, I'm not sure what the current state in logic is around notifications - they may get a notification that you responded if it was processed before the deletion, but I don't know if the notification is revoked after the deletion.